# What is the unit used by Gdal.GetGeoTransform?

Tags: python, gdal

I tried to retrieve the resolution of a raster image with Gdal in a python notebook to convert surfaces from pixels to hectares.

```py
import gdal
from osgeo import osr

src = gdal.Open(map_raster)
proj = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=src.GetProjection())
_, resx, _, _, _, resy  = src.GetGeoTransform()
src = None
```

I expected `resx` to be in meter but a `print(resx)` gave me `0.00025000000000000017` which would be very small if expressed in meters.

So my question is how can I know the unit system used by the `GetGeoTransform` function ?

**EDIT**
the `proj` value is :

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
    AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Comment: but if it's using the 'degree' unit then it's absolutely not a distance .... Is there a way to get a distance with gdal ?

Comment: Why not? https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/approx_equivalents.htm

Comment: The equivalence is given at the level of the equator, it is no longer valid if I change my latitude, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"So my question is how can I know the unit system used by the GetGeoTransform function ?"*

The units used in `GetGeoTransform` are 100% related to your coordinate system. Perhaps you can read-up about coordinate systems (there are various coordinate systems for various applications).

The two main types of coordinate systems is either a "Geographic" or a "Projected" coordinate system.
Your current file is in WGS 84 (epsg 4326) and is a geographic coordinate system and uses **degrees** as a unit. This coordinate system is widely used for display purposes (and navigation perhaps), but it is not accurate for area measurements (e.g. your true pixel size).

What you want to do is **re-project** your raster image to a **projected** coordinate system (one that is specific to the area of you image, most commonly used is the universal transverse mercator (utm), you just need to know your zone). Once the image is re-projected into a projected coordinate system your pixel size from `GetGeoTransform` will be in **meters**.

I hope that helps.

Comment: to have a value in meters, an approximate value of pixelsize in the area be obtained... starting from the bounding box of the data considered?